# specific examples of sprite classes in Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

I want a sprite class that can load a texture and draw it from anywhere. I would love it to work like this:

**First**, you would initialize.

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite( //The path would go here );
```

**Next**, you could load the sprite.

```
sprite.Load();
```

**Then** draw.

```
sprite.Draw();
```

Methods to unload and erase the sprite would also be appreciated. I would like it to contain all of the Draw arguments as well, like the following and so on

```
sprite.Layer = 0.5f;
sprite.Rotation = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

A link to a tutorial or other post would be just as good as a solution you yourself came up with. It also doesn't have to be exactly like this, it's just a loose example.

Comment: In all of my MonoGame projects a sprite is a property in a class and not a custom made class itself, since all you need is done by the Texture2D class. What is the goal you want to achieve with an own Sprite Class?

Comment: Questions asking for links, examples, tutorials, etc. are not [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Further, it seems that you are laying out the specifications you want _someone else_ to follow to write this class for you, with the expectation that this is a code-writing service.  Instead, what is the specific problem you're having? You've defined how you want this class to work, so what's stopping you from just...writing it? You will get a better response if you demonstrate what you've attempted and ask a specific question about whatever obstacle you face.

Answer (score 0):

In MonoGame, the simplest way to achieve what you want is to use the `SpriteBatch` class. You would call the `SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture2D, Vector2, Color)` method in the `Draw(GameTime)` method of your `Game1` class and pass it the appropriate fields.

There's no way for a standalone class to draw itself without some relatively complex steps. Using `Texture2D`s that you load with the `Content.Load<Texture2D>(String)` method and draw with `SpriteBatch` should be more than enough for what you're trying to accomplish.

See here for more details and other excellent MonoGame tutorials: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/spritebatch-basics